# Install Ubuntu over broken Ubuntu to recover files

Tags: data-recovery, reinstall

I broke an Ubuntu 22.04 LTS when changing some X11 configuration file. Don't remember what exactly. The machine is an Acer Nitro 5, from 2021. It is now broken on boot. It shows a sometimes blinking underscore, sometimes non blinking one. Ctrl + Alt + Fx where x goes from 1 to 6 does NOT prompt for user login and does nothing. So I thought of reinstalling ubuntu on the machine, but without wiping the hard drive data. I now have my .iso in a usb, and would like to know what steps can I follow to do so. Any suggestion is welcome.

Comment: You should always have good backups. You can do an install sometimes called a "dirty" install where you do not format partition(s). You data is preserved, but any changes you made to system or user settings will be overwritten to defaults. Or why backup is better. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UbuntuReinstallation & 
http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1941872

Comment: Backup the drive to an external hdd. Then reinstall.

Answer (score 1):

Consider and manage your risks.

Installing Ubuntu *without* reformatting is indeed one way to preserve your data and restore a working system...if the installer works the way you expect. If your filesystem is intact. If you don't make any mistakes.

But what if something goes wrong?

Protect yourself:  Use the LiveUSB's "Try Ubuntu" environment to back up your data to some other media before trying anything irreversible.

Comment: Did precisely that. Got into live os, saved the files i needed on some other usb, reinstalled everything again.

Comment: Now I am having some problems like the mousepad isn't working but at least I can boot and the bluetooth mouse does work